# How to write file to shared location on Android 11?

Tags: google-contacts-api

I've spend a lot of time and still have problem writing file to shared storage (for example downloads) on Android 11. I try to use OS file picker and getting Uri, but then no chance to create file with content. I'm always getting file not found exception "open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)".
Tried to use content resolver, but not success too. Does anybody has short java example how to create txt or pdf file with some content when you have Uri.

```
 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setType("application/pdf");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "test.pdf");

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 33333);
}



@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 33333 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The result data contains a URI for the document or directory that
            // the user selected.
            Uri uri = null;
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
                // Perform operations on the document using its URI.
                saveFile(uri);
              }

      }
}

private void saveFile(Uri sourceuri)
    {
        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(sourceuri.getPath());
            f.write(content.getBytes());
            f.close();
        }

        catch (IOException ex) {
            //result = "Error code 011: " + ex.toString();
            Log.e("SIGNAL",ex.toString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I paste your code in my activity and i figure out this solution.

I test this code in my Emulator API 30(Android 11) and it's create file test.pdf in download folder. And I notice that with out asking any permission it create file in my storage.

```
private void saveFile(Uri sourceuri) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(sourceuri);
            OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(sourceuri);

            // get the content in bytes
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            try {
                byte bytes = (byte) bufferedInputStream.read(byteArray);
                if (bytes >= 0) {
                    bufferedOutputStream.write(byteArray, 0, bytes);
                    bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                }
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
                bufferedOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```